# the specified http method is not allowed for the requested resource in servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I write controller with annotations to mapping the controller.
In the page jsp i have ajax request to the controller but i get error
"
type: Status report

message: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description: The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
"
why it's happend?

the controller class:

```
package controllers;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import model.AntiXss;
import model.HibernateToDoListDAO;
import model.Items;
import model.ToDoListDAOException;
import model.User;

@WebServlet("/DeleteMessage/*")
public class DeleteMessageController extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    HttpSession session = null;
    User user = null;
    Items item = null;
    List<Items> items = null;
    String message;
    HibernateToDoListDAO actions = HibernateToDoListDAO.getInstance();

    public DeleteMessageController()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session == null)
        {
            response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
        }
        try{
            message = request.getParameter("item");
            if(AntiXss.isUsername(message) == false )
            {
                if(session != null){
                    session.invalidate();
                }
                response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
            }
            else
            {
                items = (List<Items>)session.getAttribute("listItems");
                user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
                for(Items newItem : items)
                {
                    if(newItem.getMessage() == message && newItem.getUsername() == user.getUsername())
                    {
                        item = newItem;
                    }
                }
                actions.deleteItems(item);
                items = actions.getItems(user.getUsername());
                session.setAttribute("listItems", items);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }catch(ToDoListDAOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the jsp page:(i put here just the ajax request);

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var item = "test";
if((txtSearch(item, item.length)) == 1)
{
    var url = "DeleteMessage";
    try
    {
        xmlhttp.open("post",url,true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("item=" + item);

    }catch(e){
        alert("unable to connect to server");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use upper case for the method in `XMLHttpRequest.open()`: `xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);`

Comment: I changed it's but now he tell me unable to connect to server.

Comment: Look at the exception object (`e`), maybe it contains some more information about the error. Also, check the request with Firebug or something like that and have a look at the console. I suspect your URL is simply wrong.

Comment: I try this and he give me "xmlhttprequest.open is not a function", i search in google but i don't find something like my problem.

Comment: I found what the problems :
1) when i try in the first time to connect my app it's connect but the session destroyed,i don't know why i try to put listener but i don't see something different.
2)when i send the request ajax i can go into the controller but it's not doing the line "request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response)"

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. If you get a `XMLHttpRequest.open is not a function`, then your browser doesn't support `XMLHttpRequest` and you won't be able to send requests. Regarding your other comment, I can just advise you to add some debug logging to your controller (or use a debugger) to see what's really going on.

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. I did the debug and the ajax request work but in the controller it's not do the line: "request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response)".
Instead i get the 405 error.